# Update to array in ActiveRecord column not saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, activerecord

I have a Postgres database. One of the columns in one of my tables consists of arrays. It's called `aliases`. I'm trying to merge two instances but when I try to merge the arrays they are not saving.

```
irb(main):001:0> original
=> #<Thing id: 1, name: "Foo", aliases: ["Foo"]>
irb(main):002:0> duplicate
=> #<Thing id: 2, name: "Bar", aliases: ["Bar"]>
irb(main):003:0> original.aliases | duplicate.aliases
=> ["Foo", "Bar"]
irb(main):004:0> original.save!                      
(0.3ms)  BEGIN
Thing Exists (0.8ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "thing" WHERE "things"."name" = $1 AND ("thing"."id" != $2) LIMIT $3  [["name", "Foo"], ["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
(0.3ms)  COMMIT
Thing Store (6.1ms)  {"id":1}
=> true
```

But then when I check `original` the aliases have not merged.

```
irb(main):005:0> original
=> #<Thing id: 1, name: "Foo", aliases: ["Foo"]>
```

I tried several different ways to insert `duplicate.aliases` into `original.aliases` but nothing seems to be saving. Any ideas why? Am I missing something?

Edit:
I'm on Rails 5.1.4 and Ruby 2.5.0p0

Comment: `a | b` doesn't modify `a`. What happens when you `original.aliases = original.aliases | duplicate.aliases; original.save!`? Or `original.aliases |= duplicate.aliases`?

Comment: @muistooshort Good point. `original.aliases = original.aliases | duplicate.aliases;` works when entering it in the rails console but for some reason doesn't work when it's being run from a worker. Any ideas why?

Comment: Scrap that. It seems to be working fine now. Thanks @muistooshort. If you add as answer I can accept it.

Comment: That's pretty much the same thing that Cody said in his answer so I'd recommend accepting that one.

Answer (score 2):

Are you on Rails 3? I've noticed that Rails3 activerecord array handling does not like inline updates. You need to use a temporary variable, augment that variable and then assign it back.

```
aliases = original.aliases # make a temp variable
aliases = aliases | duplicate.aliases # modify temp variable
original.aliases = aliases # assign back
original.save! # now you can save
```

I encountered this myself when I was trying to push onto an array:

```
original.aliases << "something" # aliases would never get changed
```

Comment: I'm on Rails 5. I've updated the question. Unfortunately your suggested answer didn't work either. 